# xCode Button will not display results in label

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uibutton

For some reason when I click the calculate button it will not display my result in the label I created called resultLabel. The switch works but not the button. I am new to coding and the book for the class was for xCode 6 and I have the latest version of xCode. I have checked my code but can't seem to figure out the problem as I get no errors. Thank you for any help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
// properties for programmatically interacting with UI components
    @IBOutlet weak var switchControl: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    var w:Float = 0;
    var h:Float = 0;
    var bmi:Float = 0;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // select weightTextField so keypad displays when the view loads
        weightTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func changeSwitchLabel(_ sender: UISwitch) {


        if (sender.isOn == true) {
            switchLabel.text = "Eng"
        }
        else{
            switchLabel.text = "Met"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func calculateBMI(_ sender: Any) {
      if switchControl.isOn == true
      {
            let strW:NSString = weightTextField.text! as String as NSString
            w = strW.floatValue

            let strH:NSString = heightTextField.text! as String as NSString
            h = strH.floatValue

            bmi = (w * 702) / (h * h)
           var str = ""

            switch (bmi)
            {
            case 0...18.5:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %.2f ", bmi, ". You are Underweight") as String
            case 18.5...24.9:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %.2f ", bmi, ". You are Normal") as String
            case 25...29.9:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %.2f ", bmi, ". You are Overweight" ) as String
            default:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %2.f ", bmi, ". You are Obese") as String
            }

         resultLabel.text = str

       }
        else
       {


           let strW:NSString = weightTextField.text! as String as NSString
            w = strW.floatValue

            let strH:NSString = heightTextField.text! as String as NSString
            h = strH.floatValue

            bmi = w / (h * h)
            var str = ""

            switch (bmi)
            {
            case 0...18.5:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %.2f ", bmi, ". You are Underweight") as String
            case 18.5...24.9:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %.2f ", bmi, ". You are Normal") as String
            case 25...29.9:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %.2f ", bmi, ". You are Overweight" ) as String
            default:
                str = NSString(format: "Your BMI is %2.f ", bmi, ". You are Obese") as String
            }

            resultLabel.text = str
       }
    }


}
```

Comment: (1/2) It doesn't help to simply say you have the *latest* version of Xcode. Please, what version? (Xcode 6 is basically 2 years and versions out of date.) More importantly, what version of Swift? (Based on Xcode 6 or later, it's Swift 2.0/1/2, Swift 2.3, or Swift 3.0. But if Xcode 8.3 it's Swift 3.1.) These things matter.

Comment: (2/2) Debugging. So you have no build errors. Are your functions executing? From the code you posted *caculateBMI* is the one to (at least at the start) focus on, The simplest debug is to put a **print** statement as the very first line and see if it actually gets there. Next I'd check which part of the if statement is executing. Breakpoints will help here. Let me know what you find.

Comment: I have xcode 8.2.1 swift 3. I have no build errors. I have let it convert as I go from the old code in the book. I have tried just putting a resultLabel.text = "test" as the only action for the button to have but when I press the button nothing happens.

Comment: @Naro You need to set/connect the calculateBMI action for your calculate button in storybaord.

Comment: I was able to fix the button and get that to work but now I am having another problem.  The If statement under the button is hanging at the - var str = "" for giving bmi in lbs, when I switch to metric  which runs under the else statement it works just fine and it is the exact same code.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Finally got it all to work.